# How to inject Jenkins environment variable into maven build?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I need to get some of the Jenkins environment variables like BUILD_NUMBER and BUILD_URL and to inject them as variables in my Maven Java build.

I have added this to the pom.xml

```xml
<properties>
    <jenkins.buildUrl>${env.BUILD_URL}</jenkins.buildUrl>
</properties>
```

and while building with just mvn install I'm trying to get the variable by

```java
private static final String JENKINS_BUILD_URL = System.getProperty("jenkins.buildUrl");
```

but unfortunately the result is null...

What I'm doing wrong guys?

Comment: I have managed to get the variable by introducing this maven goal  

-Djenkins.buildUrl=${BUILD_URL}

Comment: How I can instantiate the variable without using  -Djenkins.buildUrl=${BUILD_URL}? I have a large number of Jenkins jobs and I would like to keep this in the source code rather than in Jenkins config

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Guessing you are trying to read this value into your unit tests?
Then you would have to configure the environment variables of the surefire plugin:

```xml
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
       <environmentVariables>
           <jenkins.buildUrl>${env.BUILD_URL}</jenkins.buildUrl>
       </environmentVariables>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

As stated in this documentation: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#environmentVariables

Note that it's possible to do the same in other plugin, like the Maven Tomcat Plugin for example.

Comment: Thanks, it works but I have to include new maven goal during the build phase -Djenkins.buildUrl=${BUILD_URL} in each job. Is there other way to instantiate the variable?

Comment: The Surefire configuration should suffice

Answer (score 5):

This how I achieved this in my application

Add a property in pom.xml

```xml
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>      
    <jenkins.buildNumber>${env.BUILD_NUMBER}</jenkins.buildNumber>      
</properties>
```

Create a new property in .properties file

```
jenkins.build.number = ${jenkins.buildNumber}
```

Enable filtering in maven by adding

```xml
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Then read it from java using the following code

```java
properties.load(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/project.properties"));
version = properties.getProperty("jenkins.build.number");
```

Change the maven goal as clean package -Denv.BUILD_NUMBER=${BUILD_NUMBER}

I was displaying this in our application's about page.